# How to show the "subject" in the output when sorting input of integers

Tags: java, sorting, input

I need the answer to display the lowest score and highest whilst also giving the correct subject to go along with it

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import package
class Task11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //import scanner 
        System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Financial: "); //enter for 3 subject sac scores
        int financial = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Statistics: ");
        int stats = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Networks: ");
        int network = in.nextInt();
        double average = (financial+stats+network)/3; //calculate average, use double incase of decimals

        if (financial > stats) { //determine if number1 is bigger than 2 then equal itself
        int answer = financial;
        financial = stats;
        stats = answer;
        }   

        else if (stats > network) { //same for 2 and 3
        int answer = stats;
        stats = network;
        network = answer;
        }

        else if (financial > stats) { //let it repeat itself
        int answer = financial;
        financial = stats;
        stats = answer;
        }
        int highest = network;
        int lowest = financial;
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The highest score was: " + highest);
        System.out.println("The lowest score was: " + lowest); //show user results of input


    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation did you read?

Comment: It says to display the average, highest and lowest scores through user input for 3 subjects. Then displaying the subject to answer at the end

Comment: For example: Highest score was 80 for Financial

Comment: Could you use an array or just variables?

Comment: Don't think it matters, just need the result

Answer (score 0):

This is not good-code but it can show subject in case same score:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // import scanner
    Map<Integer, List<String>> subjectScores = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Financial: "); // enter for 3
                                                         // subject sac
                                                         // scores
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int financial = in.nextInt();
    subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
    subjects.add("Financial");
    subjectScores.put(financial, subjects);
    scores.add(financial);

    System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Statistics: ");
    int stats = in.nextInt();
    if (subjectScores.containsKey(stats)) { // check if score of Statistics same with score of Financial
        subjects = subjectScores.get(stats);
        subjects.add("Statistics");
    } else {
        subjectScores.put(stats, Arrays.asList("Statistics"));
    }
    scores.add(stats);

    System.out.print("Enter SAC score for Networks: ");
    int network = in.nextInt();
    if (subjectScores.containsKey(network)) {
        subjectScores.get(network).add("Networks");
    } else {
        subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
        subjects.add("Networks");
        subjectScores.put(network, subjects);
    }
    scores.add(network);

    System.out.println(
            "The average score was: " + (financial + stats + network) / 3);

    int highestScore = Collections.max(scores);
    int lowestScore = Collections.min(scores);
    System.out.print("The highest subject was ");
    for (String subject : subjectScores.get(highestScore)) {
        System.out.print(subject + ", score: " + highestScore + ". ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("The lowest subject was ");
    for (String subject : subjectScores.get(lowestScore)) {
        System.out.print(subject + ", score: " + lowestScore + ". ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    in.close();
}
```